# multi-parameter newtype faked with a tuple?

Tags: haskell, newtype

This is a dumb question that's been bugging me for a bit. Why can't I write a newtype with multiple parameters,

```
newtype A = A Int Int
```

while the tuple version is just fine?

```
newtype A = A (Int, Int)
```

the former is much nicer in things like pattern matching.

Comment: have you read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Newtype)?

Comment: @n.m., thanks for the link, but could you elaborate on the practical concerns? Does it have to do with matching `(A _ _)`? I don't understand why the tuple equivalence would lead to unintuitive behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`newtype A = A Int` creates a type isomorphic to `Int`. That is, it behaves exactly like `Int` w.r.t. e.g. `bottom`, but under a different name.

This is in contrast with `data A = A Int` which creates a lifted type that behaves differently from Int. There's another value added that is not in `Int`: `A undefined` (which is distinct from `undefined::A`).

Now, `newtype A = A (Int, Int)` creates a type isomorphic to `(Int, Int)`. Which is, incidentally, exactly exactly what `data A = A Int Int` does.

So if we admit `newtype A = A Int Int` as being equivalent to `newtype A = A (Int, Int)`, what do we have?  `newtype A = A Int Int` is equivalent to `newtype A = A (Int, Int)` which is equivalent to `data A = A Int Int`.

`newtype A = A Int Int` is equivalent to `data A = A Int Int` (so `newtype` is redundant in this case), **but**

`newtype A = A Int` is **not** equivalent to `data A = A Int` (which is the whole point of having `newtype` in the first place).

So we must conclude that `newtype A = A Int Int` being equivalent to `newtype A = A (Int, Int)` creates redundancy and inconsistency, and we're better off not allowing it.

There's probably no way to give `newtype A = A Int Int` some other meaning which is free from these inconsistencies (or else it would be found and used I suppose ;)

Comment: You can give `newtype A = A Int Int` a meaning such that `undefined :: A = A (undefined :: Int) (undefined :: Int)` in the same way that for `newtype B = B Int` we have that `undefined :: B = B (undefined :: Int)`. This way we will have a writer monad that has a useful MonadFix instance so we can do things that like write clear declarative code to write a file as if by a template where it can store offsets to points within itself.

Answer (score 7):

Because a `newtype`, roughly speaking, works like `type` at runtime and like `data` at compile-time. Each `data` definition adds an extra layer of indirection--which, under normal circumstances, means another distinct place where something can be left as a thunk--around the values it holds, whereas `newtype` doesn't. The "constructor" on a `newtype` is basically just an illusion.

Anything that combines multiple values into one, or that gives a choice between multiple cases, necessarily introduces a layer of indirection to express that, so the logical interpretation of `newtype A = A Int Int` would be two disconnected `Int` values with nothing "holding them together". The difference in the case of `newtype A = A (Int, Int)` is that the tuple itself adds the extra layer of indirection.

Contrast this with `data A = A Int Int` vs. `data A = A (Int, Int)`. The former adds one layer (the `A` constructor) around the two `Int`s, while the latter adds the same layer around the tuple, which itself adds a layer around the `Int`s.

Each layer of indirection also generally adds a place where something can be ⊥, so consider the possible cases for each form, where ? stands for a non-bottom value:

- For `newtype A = A (Int, Int)` : `⊥`, `(⊥, ?)`, `(?, ⊥)`, `(?, ?)`
- For `data A = A Int Int` : `⊥`, `A ⊥ ?`, `A ? ⊥`, `A ? ?`
- For `data A = A (Int, Int)` : `⊥`, `A ⊥`, `A (⊥, ?)`, `A (?, ⊥)`, `A (?, ?)`

As you can see from the above, the first two are equivalent.

---

On a final note, here's a fun demonstration of just how `newtype` differs from `data`. Consider these definitions:

```
data D = D D deriving Show
newtype N = N N deriving Show
```

What possible values, including all possible ⊥s, do each of these have? And what do you think the two values below will be?

```
d = let (D x) = undefined in show x
n = let (N x) = undefined in show x
```

Load them in GHC and find out!

Comment: the fun example should use a case analysis rather than `show`, because `show` can be implemented to add the fun into any type.